# Basic proof techniques for math Olympiad

Tags: contest-math

I am very very interested in mathematical proof. I have learned basic proof techniques such as contradiction, mathematical induction, inclusion-exclusion etc.

**So, I want a list of mathematical proofs which must be basic to advanced.** 
Example...

1. Pythagorean Theorem.
2. Mathematical induction.
3. Proof by contradiction.
4. pigeonhole principle.

   ................................

   ................................

   **The second question is:** **Proofs that every mathematician should know**. I am also want to apply this proofs techniques to prove the equation that comes in math Olympiad.

Comment: The Pythagorean theorem is not a proof technique. It is a theorem.

Comment: Oh.Sorry..It may be..

Comment: You should probably break this up into two separate questions. Firstly, is there a list of 'proof techniques', if not can someone provide one. Secondly, is there a list of proofs that every mathematician should know. 

They are separate questions with separate answers.

Comment: Even your first question is too broad, probably. The second should definitely be formulated as another question.

Comment: I also think that you need to better define your focus. *Very* loosely speaking, but in a way math Olympiads are geared towards "sprint runs", while longterm math aptitude is more of a "marathon". The two are not the same, and don't necessarily work on the same optimal training curve.

Comment: @dxiv is completely right...! But if you like math Olympiads then you can see as an example,  an interesting  proof technique, called Vieta Jumping.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta_jumping

Comment: Wow this list can be very long...